# VB.NET TimeOfDay without Date

Tags: vb.net, datetime, clock

I'm trying to show the time of day using the computer's clock, but in the previous time zone (i.e. -1 hour).

I've been doing it this way:

```
        Dim Tneg1 As String = Now.AddHours(-1)
    lblClock.Text = UTCneg1
```

Where Tneg1 is a variable to represent the time with 1 hour subtracted.

However, using the *Now* property shows both the date and the hh:mm:ss. I only want the hh:mm:ss. How do I do this?

Comment: They are called `DateTime` variables for a reason

Comment: `Now.AddHours(-1).ToLongTimeString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim OneHourAgo As DateTime
Dim FormattedTime As String

OneHourAgo = Now.AddHours(-1)
FormattedTime = OneHourAgo.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

Debug.Print(FormattedTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim timeval As DateTime
        Dim newtimeval As String

        timeval = Now.AddHours(-1)
        newtimeval = Format(timeval, "hh:mm:ss")
        MsgBox(newtimeval)
```